# Communication between several php docker containers

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, containers

I have several php servers, let's name them api1, api2. I've set up docker-compose file which successfully run them in link with nginx, so they are accessible from host machine and working fine.

Here is example of my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
nginx:
    user: "root:root"
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - ./cert:/etc/nginx/ssl/
        - ./vhosts/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:cached
        - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx:cached
        - ${ACCOUNT_PATH}:/var/www/api1:cached
        - ${ACCOUNT_API_PATH}:/var/www/api2:cached
api1:
    image: php-fpm-image
    build:
        context: "."
        dockerfile: "./images/api1/Dockerfile"
    user: "root:root"
    container_name: account
    working_dir:  /var/www/api1/
    volumes:
        - api1path/:/var/www/api1
api2:
    image: php-fpm-image
    build:
        context: "."
        dockerfile: "./images/api2/Dockerfile"
    user: "root:root"
    container_name: api2
    working_dir:  /var/www/api2/
    volumes:
        - api2:/var/www/api2:cached
networks:
    default:
       name: domain.com
       driver: bridge
```

In connection with this docker-compose file for functional tests:

```
     version: '3.5'
     services:
        apitests:
           image: apitests:latest
           container_name: api_tests
           volumes:
             - ./config/:/opt/project/config/
             - ./test_reports/screenshots:/root/.selene/screenshots/
     networks:
       default:
       driver: bridge
       external:
          name: domain.com
```

There are next domains which are accessible from host machine:

> api1.domain.com 127.0.0.1
>
> api2.domain.com 127.0.0.1

My problem is how to connect them directly inside docker, because I need to do requests from api1 to api2, apitests to api1, api2.

When I do request, their domain resolving directly to their containers, so I receive next error

> can't connect to remote host (172.21.0.8): Connection refused

from any container.

As you understand, I need that their domains resolve to NGINX container, so it can work correctly and php-fpm can return result via nginx back to me.

How do can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your problem is that you've named php container as api1.domain.com when your requirements are to assign this domain name for nginx container.

You could assign api1/api2 aliases to nginx inside container networks.

```
services:
   nginx:
      networks:
        default:
          aliases:
            - api1
            - api2
```

Comment: And I suppose if you want to resolve their domain names from nginx, you should also 'link' them to nginx container.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you very much. It works like a charm. I've just made a little update to match my example. network is default and full domain path not needed :)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you have several `docker-compose.yml` files and need services from them to interact with each other. The logic suggestion is to have a globally-defined network, lets say

```
docker network create testapis
```

and have all services linked to it:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
networks:
  default:
    external: 
      name: testapis
```

In this case all services from all `docker-compose` files will see each other under their hostnames (`api1`, `api2`, etc) and no port exposing would be needed (unless you want to use services from outside this net)

Comment: Nope, I already have network, and my services see each other by their container names. But I need to send request to api1.domain.com, and it must go to nginx container. But now request on api.domain.com goes to api1 container, and php do not proceed it, as it must to work via webserver to serve requests.